# Php, Mysql can't retrieve column data for each row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to give each modal form a unique id based on results retrieved from my database so that different data will be passed onto the php form processor. I have 1 table that is placed in a form which has the unique value for each row being "`mapid`"

However, each row also has a modal which I've placed another form in but the only value I'm getting is the first row of the sql query. Please help.

```
    $sql = "SELECT mapid, location, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%y') AS date, status FROM maps ORDER BY status DESC, date DESC ";    
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo
'
<form action="map.php" method="post">

    <tr>

        <td> '. $row["mapid"].' </td>

        <td> '. $row["location"].' </td>

        <td> ' . ($row["status"]=='0' ? 'Last Done' : (($row["status"]=='1') ? 'Started' : 'Done')).' </td>

        <td> '.$row["date"].' </td>

        <td> ' . 
        (($row["status"]=='0') ?
            '<input type="hidden" name="mapid" value="'. $row["mapid"].'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="start" value="start"/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="getmap" type="submit">Start</button>'

        : (($row["status"]=='1') ? 
            '<input type="hidden" name="mapid" value="'. $row["mapid"].'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="resume" value="resume"/>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="getmap" value="'. $row["mapid"].'">Resume</button>'

        : (($row["status"]=='2') ?
           '<input type="hidden" name="mapid" value="'. $row["mapid"].'"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="process" value="process"/>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="getmap">Process</button>' 
        : ''))) . '

        </td>
</form>


        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assign['. $row["mapid"].']">Assign</button>
        </td>

        <div class="modal fade" id="assign['. $row["mapid"].']" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="assignLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="work/allocate.php" method="post">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="assignLabel">Assign Map</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" name="mapid">
                    <p> Assign <strong>Map '. $row["mapid"].' - '. $row["location"].' </strong> to:</p>
                    <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" >
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="assigned" id="assigned" type="submit">Assign</button>
                </div>

               </form>

    </tr>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    '
```

Comment: What you get if you user `print_r()` to print the data fetched from database? Also have you tried to run your query in `mysql` what does it return there inside of database?

Comment: The first '. $row["mapid"].' in the first form outputs correctly. Each row increments so that I have mapid 1, 2, and 3. However, if I place '. $row["mapid"].'  anywhere in the second form, I will only get mapid 1.

Comment: Turns out, I needed to give the Modals a unique id. Code is edited and working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to give the modal a unique id by adding ['. $row["mapid"].'] next to #assign.

```html
 <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assign['. $row["mapid"].']" value"">Assign</button>
        </td>
        
        
        
        <div class="modal fade" id="assign['. $row["mapid"].']" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="assignLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
```